# I want to automatically update a table when my second table updated in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have  table Table A and Table B.

Now I want to Update my Table A automatically when my Table B is Updated or created.

Table A value is updated by Table B value where Table A name = Table B name

Both have 3 columns lastname, name, value.

This is my update query but i want to update it automatically so i don't want to run it again & again.

```
UPDATE `transformation bi`.`Table A` t1       
     JOIN `transformation bi`.`Table B` t2  
ON t1.name = t2.name   
SET t1.value = t2.value`   
 WHERE t1.Name = t2.Name;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should use triggers.

Comment: I don't how to write it can u pls explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tow ways to do this,

**Stored Procedure for both update query**

1. You can create a store procedure which can be triggered at one query or in following way

**Below Query**

```
    UPDATE Table A, Table B
    SET Table A.yourFColm=yourVal,
    Table B.yourFColm=yourVal,
    Table A.yourFColm=yourVal,
    WHERE t1.Name = t2.Name;
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: My update query is running fine But i want to convert it into trigger or Store procedure. So how can i do this.

Comment: This will help you [Click Here](http://www.sqlinfo.net/mysql/mysql_stored_procedure_UPDATE.php)

Comment: Yes it is helpful